# Unable to launch Ride for Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am a newbie in automation. I have 64bit windows 10 Machine. I have installed 
python 2.7.11 and
wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.2.0-py27.exe and also
set up environment variables

Still when i launch ride using ride.py in cmd it does nothing. I have also tried using ride.py in C:\Python27\Scripts folder but nothing. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of code. Take the time to properly copy, paste, and format the information directly in the question.

Comment: Understood/apologies, I removed that image of Pip List as the issue was with wxPython version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several wrong versions of packages. These are the steps you need to do:

```
pip uninstall robotframework-ride
pip uninstall wxPython
pip install wxPython==4.0.7.post2
pip install robotframework-ride
```

The version will be 1.7.4.2 (there was a problem on the packaging and it does not install the correct wxPython version).

Comment: hats off to you Sir Helio